# Phenomenon of $stateParms

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a phenomenon with `$stateParams` that I want to undrestand :

I have this code to pass through states  : 
 **In my controller :**

```
$scope.goToPath = function ( path, pid ) {


    $scope.pid = pid;
    console.log("scope pid : " + $scope.pid + " Full path : " + $state.current.name);
    $state.go(path, {projectId : pid} );
};
```

In **my state definition** :

```
state('projects.detail', {
             url: '/detail',
             params : { projectId : null},
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/detail/detailProject.html',
             title: 'Detail du projet',
        });
```

And then I'm calling **this function** with `ng-init` :

```
$scope.getProjectById = function () {

    projectFactory.getProject($stateParams.projectId)
        .success(function (data) {
            if(data == null){
                $scope.errorMessage = "Le projet avec l'id : " + pid + " n'existe pas";
            }else {

                $scope.project = data;
                $scope.project.dateDebut =  new Date(data.dateDebut);
                $scope.project.dateFin =  new Date(data.dateFin);
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Erreur 1: " + data.error + ' ' + status;
        });
};
```

And as you can see here I'm passing `$stateParams.projectId` the value stated in my state definition.

And in **my factory** I have :

```
 factory.getProject = function (projectId) {
    console.log('Project Id factory : '+ projectId + $stateParams.projectId);
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/Project/' + $stateParams.projectId)
};
```

Now when I ran this I got : `projectId = undefined` AND `$stateParams.projectId = 4`
now I'm passing the projectId in the function so normally it should have a value, no ?
   Can someone explain this, it will much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Where did you define the `getProjectById` function ?

Comment: In My controller the same as `goToPath()`

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a design problem :

Let's say this is your app's HTML :

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <a href ng-click="goToPath('detail', 234)">redirect</a>
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have an app controller that will handle the redirection. You are passing `/detail` to the `$state.go` function. This function takes the state's name not URL.

Then, the second function which should be called by the `ng-init` of the state's template, is declared in the app's controller.

For me, it should be declared in the state's controller :

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state){
        $scope.goToPath = function ( path, pid ) {
        alert(path + ' ' + pid);
        $scope.pid = pid;
      $state.go(path, {projectId : pid} );
    };
  })
    .config(routes);

function routes($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('detail', {
            url: '/detail',
             params : { projectId : null},
             template: '<div ng-init="getProjectById()">ok</div>',
             title: 'Detail du projet',
             controllerAs: 'detail',
             controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
               $scope.getProjectById = function () {
                 alert($stateParams.projectId)
               } 
              }
        });
}
```

[I jsfiddled the solution here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmsumk2v/24/)

With this code, you are able to get your `projectId` and then pass it to your service.

Comment: actually that's what I'm doing as the two states wich I'm passing value in between are childrens of a parent state, so they have a shared controller like this : `function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('projects', {
                url: '/projects',
                template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true"></ui-view>',
                abstract: true,
                title: 'Les projets',
                controller : 'ProjectController'
            })`...Children definition ...